# Y range origin seems to be off for one point?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have three points in a line graph in my program. The first two are working just fine, but the third point's y coordinate seems to be about 1.5 units more than what is indicated by the graph's scale. I'm not really sure why this is happening, since the other two are just fine and this one uses the same scale as the other two.

After looking at it for a while, it seems like the third point's y pixel doesn't equal zero at the top of the graph, but rather a little bit above, where the svg isn't present.

Diagram:

```
------------------------------ <-- y pixel val = 0

_______________________________
|                             |
|                             |
|                             |
|            svg              |
|                             |
|                             |
|                             |
------------------------------
```

While testing it, I replaced the third point's y with 0, but, as can be seen in https://jsfiddle.net/xv8ggm0n/1/ , it is plotted as 4. Honestly, this seems more like a bug, but considering how rare that is I'm not sure what's wrong.

For reference, here's the full code: https://jsfiddle.net/xv8ggm0n/

Comment: you are using a function to set the y value taking in your x and y that you defined as 4, 0, specifically: (Math.pow(xval, 3) * xthree + xval * xval * xtwo + xval * xone + xzero). What are you expecting this to return for Y?

Comment: Oh, sorry, I figured it out already. I'll post the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that because my equation for my coefficients was slightly incorrect, the difference caused some sort of error. I'm not sure why it went wrong, but the graph will  be fixed if the equation is correct